I believe ive been robbed
I have the transaction 0x8718fb0123b9335ced0a2e450ef28904bf972645c43d0e6e59ad3065888879df that I did not approve of and it seems my crypto was maliciously transfered out of my wallet I believe on purpose because I had gotten in early on a token and usually i have to scan my thumbprint for this to occur i have never witnessed anything like this ever before. This is the swap 0x168ef26202b44751845cafa88155bdebee28ba9eeb98c3e79a05a05b325c2eae and confirmed it did arrive in my wallet I even have a picture of it. As soon as it arrived the first transaction occurs and my token dissapears and now it's not showing up in my wallet. Can anyone tell me how something like this could've happened? Only if it's a scam token would it be worthless and non swappable but for something to literally leave my wallet just does not make any sense.

Likely that when you bought the scam token, you unknowingly signed over access to your wallet's operations to the developer, which gives them access to your private key which they can use to take the crypto out of your wallet without authorization.
You need to always be aware of what transaction you're approving, especially when its not from a valid source.
